# Why is helper called multiple times in this scenario?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I have a template:

```
<template name="addform">
{{#if editmode}}
<form class="form-inline phonebook-edit" role="form">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="name">Name:</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" value="{{datatoedit.name}}" name="personname">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="pwd">Phone:</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" value="{{datatoedit.phone}}" name="phoneno" id="pwd">
    <input type="hidden" value="{{datatoedit._id}}" name="id">
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Edit</button>
</form>
{{else}}
<form class="form-inline phonebook-add" role="form">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="name">Name:</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="personname">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="pwd">Phone:</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="phoneno" id="pwd">
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Add</button>
</form>
{{/if}}
</template>
```

and a helper:

```
Template.addform.helpers({

  'editmode':function(){
    return Session.get('editmode');  
  },
'datatoedit': function(){
        if(Session.get('idtoedit')) {
            var phonebookdata = Phonebook.findOne({"_id":Session.get('idtoedit')});
            console.log(phonebookdata);
            return phonebookdata;
        } else {
            return "world";
        }
        //return Session.get('idtoedit');
    }    

  });
```

Editmode is a flag which switches the add / edit form which is working great.

datatoedit is the data we get from mongodb using the _id placed in session.

In the template I had to call this datatoedit in 3 different places to put value in each text box.

My question is how do I make meteor call mongodb only one time and get all the data I need to put them in text boxes.

I placed a console.log which prints the same data trice. This made me wonder why meteor is going to mongo everytime for printing name, phone and _id value

I'm new to meteor. Please suggest a proper way to build an edit form to me. I want the mongodb to be called once and send those data which I should put them in edit text boxes.

http://phonebook.meteor.com/ open console tab and hit edit in different row you will see the issue which is described above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a pattern which should do the trick:

```
<template name="addform">
{{#if editmode}}
<form class="form-inline phonebook-edit" role="form">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="name">Name:</label>
    {{#with datatoedit}}
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" value="{{this.name}}" name="personname">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="pwd">Phone:</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" value="{{this.phone}}" name="phoneno" id="pwd">
      <input type="hidden" value="{{this._id}}" name="id">
    {{/with}}
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Edit</button>
</form>
{{else}}
<form class="form-inline phonebook-add" role="form">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="name">Name:</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="personname">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="pwd">Phone:</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="phoneno" id="pwd">
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Add</button>
</form>
{{/if}}
</template>
```

Basically the `{{#with datatoedit}}` is setting the data context for the block of html to `this` once and then you're accessing the 3 keys of the `this` object.

Comment: .  yeah, that should work.  here's a minimal meteorpad example  http://meteorpad.com/pad/duHXPWC4kPGB74gz5/WithExample  .    It works also if  you write 'fieldName', instead of 'this.fieldName'.   but perhaps using 'this' is more clear, it reminds the reader of the custom context.